# How do I treat $(this) as an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, element, extend

I'm building an extended function to apply to any given element:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        SomeFunction: function() {
            var $this = $(this);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

In a script tag, I would drop:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.someclassname').SomeFunction();
});
```

This works fine, except that I want to be able to reference the scope of the function as the element and not as the function, as you can see in my one variable declaration.  For some reason, it's not treating it like an element where I can apply things like:

```
$this.css('background','red');
```

In order for it to work, I have to change it to:

```
var $this = $('.someclassname');
```

How can I program the extended function so that $this refers to the element to which SomeFunction is being applied? I'd rather it not care what the class name is.

Thanks!

Comment: [Seems to work here](http://jsfiddle.net/27hv3/1/)

Comment: Where are you trying to do `$this.css('background', 'red');`? It's within `SomeFunction`, correct? (And not outside, which would not have access to `SomeFunction`s local variable, `$this`)

Comment: I don't understand the description of your problem. Where are you trying to do what? Only going by your last sentence / question, using `this` will work. Please see the documentation: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `SomeFunction`, `this` is not a DOM element, it's a jQuery instance. (Plugins are very different from event handlers.) That instance may have zero, one, or multiple matching DOM elements inside it.

So `this.css("background", "red");` would work. E.g.:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        SomeFunction: function() {
            this.css("background", "red");
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/wotuqoja/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/wotuqoja/1/edit)

If your goal is to use the set from *outside* `SomeFunction` (maybe `SomeFunction` does filtering of some kind?), usually you'd do that by doing your filtering and returning the jQuery object with the (filtered) results. (If not filtering, the convention is to return `this` [the full set].)

So for instance, suppose `SomeFunction` is only supposed to return elements containing the text `"kittens"`:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        SomeFunction: function() {
            return this.filter(function() {
                return $(this).text().indexOf("kittens") !== -1;
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.someclassname').SomeFunction().css("background", "red");
});
```

would only affect elements with `someclassname` that contained the text `"kittens"`: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/wotuqoja/3) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/wotuqoja/3/edit)

Comment: Doesn't jQuery just return the same set when provided a jQuery object?

Comment: I have an unrelated question. How do you highlight inline words in posts, such as you've done with "SomeFunction", "this", and the css example? I reviewed the SO markdown help document, but couldn't find any examples on this inline highlighting.

Comment: @MichaelRyan: The backtick (```) character.

Comment: Many ```thanks```! I apparently failed to expand that first section. :\

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer: Hmmm, good point, yes, a different jQuery object but the same contents. So it's not clear what the question actually is.

Comment: Thanks, TJ! This did work. I think the problem I was having in part had to do with missing a period when selecting en element by class name. I swear: 99% of issues I have with JS is dumb things like that.

Comment: @linnium: You and the rest of us. :-)